# URL Rewrite Module (web.config) file for ms azure

Tags: azure, url, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a "web. config" file as below. Rule 1 works fine but Rule 2 didn't work no matter what I did. Please assist me with this matter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}&amp;req_id={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If rule 1 matches everything and then stops processing, then rule 2 never executes. Use FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean I need to write just a rule? thanx @lex-li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue as below,

```
   <rule name="rule 1">
            <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$"  />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}"  />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 2">
            <match url="^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/req_id/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)?$"  />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}&amp;req_id={R:2}"  />
        </rule>
```